# Need Explaination: plug in method with delegates

Tags: c#, delegates

I'm new at C# and I've been studying it for a month now. And some code is giving me a headache. Could you please explain me how this works, how can the void method in the Util class change the int array in the Test class? (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/orm-9780596527570-03-04.aspx)

I don't understand how the line `values[i] = t(values[1])` can change the `mainvalues[]` eventhough it's void without ref or out? If it's possible then please explain it for a C# beginner.

Thanks for your time!

```
public delegate int Transformer (int x);

public class Util
{
  public static void Transform (int[] values,Transformer t)
  {
   for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
   values[i] = t(values[i]);
  }
}

class Test
{
  static void Main(  )
  {
    int[] mainvalues = new int[] {1, 2, 3};
    Util.Transform(mainvalues, Square);      // dynamically hook in Square
    foreach (int i in mainvalues)
      Console.Write (i + "  ");           // 1   4   9
  }

  static int Square (int x) { return x * x; }
}
```

Comment: I think you are bit confused with what a function is returning and what is taking as an argument...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because arrays are reference types.Even if you don't use `ref` keyword it will be passed as reference.You are changing the values of array inside of your method.You are passing each value to `Square` method and getting the the result then replace the each number with the new result.

`values[i]` is an `int`, it is passed by value and `t(values[i])` returns a new value (doesn't change the value that you have).The important part is you are assigning it back.That's why it changes the original value.

Answer (score 0):

To fully understand it you have to see how the code works, if you are using *visual studio* you can go to **Debug** chose **Step In To** and walk through the code by clicking **Step In To** over and over again till your code terminates. That's how I understood it myself.